# Which view class should I use?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gallery

I am going to implement an image viewer, where I want to show one image at a time.

When the user touches the image with their finger and move the image to left/right, the next image should show.

I am wondering which **view class** I should use for this kind of image viewer? (Some kind of image list???)

P.S.: During the display of the current image, the neighbor(left & right) images are not visible, that is, the current image occupies the whole view area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Gallery view, see [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html).

To ensure that only one image is shown at a time, you can either

- Set the image width to match the screen width (using ImageView.[setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29))

  ```
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  ```
- Set the spacing of the gallery (using Gallery.[setSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setSpacing%28int%29)). Experiment with the spacing value until you get the desired result.

Comment: @videre, thank you. but which class I should extends to use that tutorial oncreate()?? myGalleryClass extends Gallery{code in tutorial} ??

Comment: @Leem: It takes 5 minutes to follow the tutorial, do that and then come back if you still have questions. The tutorial is very straight-forward, follow each step and you'll have a working Gallery doing exactly what you described in your question. Afterwards experiment with the size of the images and the spacing between them.

Comment: @videre, I can not figure out what is 'styleable' in the tutorial code? If it is an xml file, what is the content, there is no place explain the 'styleable' anyhow... and where should it be placed. I have followed the tutorial, but there is no explanation for this, I can not just guess...

Comment: @Leem: I assume you're referring to this part: ´TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(android.R.styleable.Theme);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                android.R.styleable.Theme_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle(); ´ I think it adds a grey frame to the images, but is not important, you can comment these lines out if you want. If you do that, you'll also have to remove the line: i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground); Are you able to run the application?

Comment: @videre, yes I can run my application, now it works. Thank you. How about show one image at one time? the current gallery show several images...

Comment: in onCreate(), set the spacing between the images with: ´g.setSpacing(/*some integer*/)´. Experiment until you find the right spacing

Answer (score 1):

Gallery class is deprecated, try using ViewPager.